# Weex - I have android files, what's next

Tags: android-studio, vue.js, weex

I started playing with the weex and I have a problem because I do not know what to do next.
Using the command - weex platform add android, I created an android folder

[image]

In the documentation I am writing to download the android studio and use the command - weex run android
but I do not work, nwm I'm doing something wrong or I just do not have the right tools installed.

I would like to create a file that the phone will recognize and install the application

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'I would like to create a file that the phone will recognize and install the application'.
Are your going to enhance weex by adding some customer module？

Write a Class like `TestModule` which extends `WXModule` and put in any path your like.

The register your `TestModule` in `WXSDKEngine`, by `WXSDKEngine.registerComponent("test", TestModule.class);`